# Bulk decrypt multiple PDF files

Tags: automator, pdf, encryption

I have received a selection of PDF files (about 40) that are all encrypted with the same password. I'd rather not have them be encrypted because it's annoying to enter the password every time and I already have full disk encryption anyways.

How can I decrypt all of these PDF files without having to manually open and re-save each and every file? I looked in Automator but I only found an option to Encrypt PDF, not Decrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a third-party utility named [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) that can be compiled from *source*, or installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), i.e.:

```
brew install qpdf
```

Then *change directory* to where the encrypted **PDF** *files* are, assuming they are in a *directory* by themselves, and use the following *compound command*, e.g.:

```
for f in *.[pP][dD][fF]; do qpdf --decrypt --password=password "${f}" "${f%.*}-decrypted.${f##*.}"; done
```